# Wildfly 10 not enabling deployment

Tags: java, wildfly

I have been doing a few tests with the production server, i deactivated the production deployment and uploaded similar war modified,made the testing then removed the war file, now i can't enable the production deployment, it just freezes, if a change to another web page i get a message "unable to modify deployent" or i click the 'enable' button and stay there like nothing happened.

There's an alternate way to enable the deployment? the production war file is actually stable so i have no idea why is doing this.

**Wildfly log:**

```
2016-08-25 14:37:06,520 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (management task-8) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$1@381f4b55 for
operation {"operation" => "deploy","address" => [("deployment" => "productionDeployment.war")],"operation-headers" => {"access-mechanism" => "HTTP"}} at address [("deployment" =>
"productionDeployment.war")] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 

2016-08-25 14:37:15,436 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
(management task-8) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated
the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "productionDeployment.war")]' 

2016-08-25 14:43:48,145 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-5)
WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "productionDeployment.war")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0343: The service container has been destabilized by a
previous operation and further runtime updates cannot be processed. Restart is required." 

2016-08-25 14:44:05,431 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management
task-5) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service
container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "productionDeployment.war")]' 2016-08-25 14:46:21,240 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to
start service jboss.deployment.unit."productionDeployment.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."productionDeployment.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153:
Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "productionDeployment.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:110)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**another relevant log:**

```
10:18:33,167 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."cdmxturismo.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cdmxturismo.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "cdmxturismo.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cdmxturismo.session is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:768)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.installSessionManagerFactory(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:421)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:338)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentProcessor.deploy(UndertowDeploymentProcessor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

10:18:33,189 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-5) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cdmxturismo.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cdmxturismo.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cdmxturismo.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"cdmxturismo.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cdmxturismo.session is already registered"}}
10:18:33,191 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management task-5) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "cdmxturismo.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cdmxturismo.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cdmxturismo.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"cdmxturismo.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cdmxturismo.session is already registered"}}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. Seems you deployed a different version of the war and after a test get back to the previous one. That should not an be an issue. Could you explain what you exact do and show the logfile messages?

Comment: @wfink added the log

Comment: I figured what was wrong, someone uploaded war file a different name but it was deactivated, i guess it had the same `<context-root>/crawlazo</context-root>`, so just deleted this one, and it works fine again